# <AWS S3> How to archive files to a folder with date as the prefix?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

There is a requirement to archive files inside a bucket folder (i.e. put under prefix) for those files having last modified date exceeding a particular time (say 7 days) to a subfolder with date as the prefix:

Sample folder structure:

> a.txt
> b.txt
>
> > 20210826
> >
> > > c.txt (with last modified date over 1 week)

> > 20210819
> >
> > > > d.txt (with last modified date over 2 weeks)

Any idea how this can be achieved? It seems there's no readily-available archiving policy to achieve this.

The only way I can think of is through a lambda function (with scheduler trigger) to :

- Scan all the files timestamp to see which are older than 1 week
- Move the matched files to under a prefix (e.g. 20210826/c.txt)

Another question is about purging. If files are put under a date prefix, how can we configure the LifecycleConfiguration Rule in the CloudFormation template?

```
  LifecycleConfiguration:
    Rules:
      - Id: DeletionRule
        Prefix: '' (how to set it to cater for different dates as the key)
        Status: Enabled
        ExpirationInDays: !FindInMap [EnvironmentsMap, !Ref env, S3FileRetentionIndays]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [configure a lifecycle rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-set-lifecycle-configuration-intro.html) that transitions the objects after x time to a different storage class, and then, capture that operation using Event Bridge based on the CloudTrail API called. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-ct-api-tutorial.html

Finally, Event Bridge triggers a Lambda function that moves the S3 object to a subfolder with the date prefix.

Regarding the expiration configuration, you'll need to create a parent folder for all the purged files and set that as the prefix.

Your Cloudformation template will look like this:

```
LifecycleConfiguration:
Rules:
  - Id: DeletionRule
    Prefix: 'purged-files/'
    Status: Enabled
    ExpirationInDays: !FindInMap [EnvironmentsMap, !Ref env, S3FileRetentionIndays]
```